# Smtp Gmail Not Working As I tried All in live server

Tags: laravel

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465 
MAIL_USERNAME=some-email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

I tried ssl and tls with their respective code but shows Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]

```
 Mail::send('email.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
           $message->from($data['email']);
           $message->to('abc@gmail.com', 'Admin');
          });
```

Comment: Can you provide any additional details about your environment?  A connection timeout means that you are unable to reach the server, which could be an issue with a firewall.

Comment: try, `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp`

Comment: Check smtp cridencial online  (https://www.smtper.net/)

Answer (score 7):

Generally gmail is not recommended to send emails on live server, but if you just using it for testing purpose than make sure you have allowed `less secure app` to YES under https://myaccount.google.com/security and allow captcha at https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha.

After performing above actions just clear your cache and email should work fine.

Comment: If you are still facing issue , please create APP password by visiting https://myaccount.google.com/security , you need to enable 2 factor authentication before generating APP password which can be disabled later on,

Answer (score 1):

You are trying with 465 port with SMTP which is fine but can to try with 587 port.